# Power rating and operating voltage

Tags: voltage, power, lighting

What does it mean when a lightbulb is rated at 60W with 220V?

My understanding is that the input power to the lightbulb will be 60W. But what about 220V? Is it the amount of voltage the lightbulb should use?

What if you place multiple lightbulbs in series and use a 220V power supply? 220V is no longer dropped across it?

Comment: The discussion around this question may also be of interest: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/101268/how-to-determine-required-voltage-of-a-lightbulb

Comment: Please add to the question body: Is this about *incandescent* light bulbs (simple), or does it include discharge&LED lamps (frustrating)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Device ratings in general can be confusing.  Usually if a device that consumes power is rated at X Volts, that means that all the other ratings hold when you hold its input to X Volts.  Also usually, if a device is rated at Y Watts at X Volts, then that *either* means it will consume Y Watts, or in the case of things that can be turned up or down, it'll consume *no more than* Y Watts at X Volts.

Incandescent lights are easy -- run them at the rated voltage, and they'll consume the rated power.

LED and CFL bulb ratings are an abomination unto reason, in that if you apply rated voltage to them they'll make as much light as some "standard" incandescent bulb, in the visible range*.  They'll do this while consuming a fraction of the *actual* power.  In fact, I think I'm going to start calling the rating "double-u" to irritate my relatives.  As in "go pick up some 60 double-u bulbs at the store, please".

If you take multiple incandescent bulbs and connect them in series, each one will get less voltage.  Each one will be dimmer -- and redder.  I'm pretty sure that the whole string will consume more current than Ohm's law would lead you to believe, because cold filaments have less resistance than hot ones.  I'm also quite sure that for the overall power consumed, the whole string will be dimmer in the visible than bulbs running at their rated power -- because the filaments will be cooler, which means they'll be redder, which means they'll put out more of their power in the IR instead of the visible.

* I currently work at a company that sells sensors operating at 940 and 850nm wavelengths -- typical florescent and LED lighting sheds no light at these wavelengths.  But incandescents do.

Comment: Its an interesting one. Do datasheets tend to provide the resistance of a component at a specific temperature?

Comment: If the manufacturer thinks the customer base cares, and if they think that it makes their product look better, and if they're sophisticated enough to actually know -- yes.  Otherwise no.

Answer (score 1):

> What does it mean when a lightbulb is rated at 60W with 220V? My understanding is that the input power to the lightbulb will be 60W. But what about 220V? Is it the amount of voltage the lightbulb should use?

Yes.

> What if you place multiple lightbulbs in series and use a 220V power supply? 220V is no longer dropped across it?

Correct. In this configuration, 220 V is no longer dropped across each bulb. If the bulbs are old-fashioned incandescent types, they will be noticeably dimmer when operated this way. I think they will still glow but look dim and orange-ish. It is also possible that some bulbs will be brighter and some dimmer. I don't think I have ever done this exact experiment so I am not sure about that part. I have run bulbs at reduced voltage and they definitely look dimmer.

If they are LED types, then they will likely not operate properly but the details are hard to predict.